# git clone makes an error zsh: parse error near '\n'

Tags: git, github, parse-error

`git clone -b (github_id) --single-branch <https://github.com/(github_id)/repository>`

then the error is

`zsh: parse error near '\n'`

i tried:

1. check my git config file

```
[user]
    name = (myname)
    email = (myemail)

[core]
    editor = code --wait
    autocrlf = input
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

2. check my json file

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
    "typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single"
}
```

what can i do?

Comment: Are the `<` and `>` literally there?

Comment: do you have special characters in the `git clone` command? I don't use `zsh`, but seeing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278748/zsh-parse-error-near-n-when-adding-aws-keys-as-environment-variables, it seem probable that some special characters somewhere are causing trouble with zsh.

Comment: oh! thank you.. the problem was `<` and `>`.

Comment: Angle brackets (`git clone <url>`) are a typographical convention meaning *replace this text, including the angle brackets, with something appropriate to your situation*. Square brackets (`git clone [-b <branch>] <url>`) indicate something *optional:* here, `-b` (literally) and a space and then a branch name, which—being enclosed in angle brackets—means that you should come up with appropriate replacement text.

Answer (score 1):

As [seen here](https://programmerah.com/solved-zsh-one-of-the-solutions-to-parse-error-near-n-32775/), using a `git clone <url>` would trigger the error message you are seeing.
Instead, this would work, *without* `<>`:

```
git clone -b github_id --single-branch https://github.com/github_id/repository
```